# Join user to custom table

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom table (myusersession) which contains the *uid* field that is a reference to user entities.

How can I add user entity fields (exactly 'name') to my view?

I tried many variations of join, in `hook_views_data()`, but none of them works.

```
  $data['myusersession']['table']['join'] = array(
    'users_field_data' => array(
      'field' => 'uid',
      'left_field' => 'uid',
    ),
  );

  $data['myusersession']['uid'] = array(
    'title' => t('UID'),
    'help' => t(''),
    'field' => array(
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('User'),
      'help' => t(''),
      'base' => 'users',
      'base field' => 'uid',
      'id' => 'standard',
    ),
  );
```

I also tested variations of the table name, such as users_field_data, users, and user.

As I understand the following code should be work, but it doesn't in my case.

```
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => $this->t('User'),
      'label' => $this->t('User'),
      'base' => 'users',
      'base field' => 'uid',
      'relationship field' => 'uid',
    ),
```

With `['table']['join']`, the table appears as column on the view with *User* as base, but but if the view base is *myusersession*, *User* doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Relationship b/w users_field_data and myusersession
  $data['myusersession']['uid']['relationship'] = [
    'title' => t('User'),
    'help' => t('Relate User.'),
    'id' => 'standard',
    'base' => 'users_field_data',
    'base field' => 'uid',
    'field' => 'uid',
    'label' => t('User'),
  ];
  return $data;
```

This code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Found that there is additional step: you have to add/enable that relationship at View GUI->Advanced->Relationship